# Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing error while interacting with webservice

Tags: php, angularjs, json, web-services

I am trying to read json data through a webservice but I am unable to retrieve data.  If I use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` plugin for Google Chrome browser then it works. However this is a temporary workaround. Even if I use `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>` in top of my php page it does not work, since I get the following error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myurl/getParameters. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myurl/getParameters. (Reason: CORS request failed)
```

Comment: `...in top of my php page` what php page? The webservice needs to return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Answer (score 0):

The remote API should be configured to access CORS requests. Otherwise, you cannot interact with the web-service.